# Can you set `Go to declaration or usages` to not go to the type declaration in PhpStorm?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I am often going to methods via the `GoTo Declaration or Usages` shortcut (mouse scroll click).

This works totally fine for any normal JS / PHP method, but when using TypeScript its always going to the type / interface.

I don't want that, I want to go to the method.  Is that possible to change / is there another `go to` that would work better in this situation?

### Edit

Including some examples

Mouse scroll click on relationship
[image]

I want it to go here (actual method)
[image]

But it goes here (type declaration)
[image]

Comment: Have you got an example?

Comment: @AlexR updated with image examples

Comment: do both files belong to the project, or installed as a library (node module)? Is the first file original `.ts` file, or generated `.js` file? did you try excluding the `d.ts` file from indexing?

Comment: its my project, so not an external package.  I have not tried to exclude `d.ts` from indexing, I still want all the IntelliSense, but I just want the `Go To` to go to the actual method, not the type declaration